# How do I retrieve the Task ID of a task process?

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

I am trying to retrieve the task IDs of tasks in a task process in order to retrieve their task status. The only field that shows is the task outcome, which doesn't help. How do I get the task ID?